# run puppeteer without desktop environment

Tags: puppeteer

Is possible to run puppeteer on my Debian environment ? I don't have the desktop environment installed on it.

When I run my example.js script I have a `Error: Failed to launch chrome! libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

Install the Debian required dependencies to use chromium:

```
apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

And launch the browser without the sandbox:

example.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some useful documentation here:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker

The use of `--no-sandbox` is described as "strongly discouraged", but there are hints about running Puppeteer in a Docker container which should solve the missing shared libraries issues.

The Dockerfile suggested in the above mentioned link is:

```sh
FROM node:12-slim

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# If running Docker >= 1.13.0 use docker run's --init arg to reap zombie processes, otherwise
# uncomment the following lines to have `dumb-init` as PID 1
# ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_x86_64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /node_modules

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser

CMD ["google-chrome-stable"]
```

Then the suggested Docker build and run commands are:

```sh
docker build -t puppeteer-chrome-linux .
```

```sh
 docker run -i --init --rm --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN \
   --name puppeteer-chrome puppeteer-chrome-linux \
   node -e "`cat yourscript.js`"
```

I tested the process described here above myself , and after that received a `no usable sandbox` error (therefore the missing shared object error appeared to be solved by it).

Concerning the sandbox related error, suggested resolution from the same source than mentioned here above, is enabling user namespace cloning.

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thank you for your reviews. I have included essential parts of the answer here.